# How To Set Minimum Degree Of Parallelism For Parallel.ForEachAsync

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have the following C# code that sends get requests for some array of urls in parallel:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] urls = { "https://example1.com", "https://example2.com", "https://example3.com", "https://example4.com", "https://example5.com" };
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = urls.Length };
                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(urls, options, async (url, stoppingToken) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing " + url);
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine("Response for " + url + " " + resp);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Response for " + url + " " + ex.Message);
                    }
                });
                Console.WriteLine("Completed");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

If I set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism to the size of the array, does this also act as an implied minimum degree of parallelism?
Meaning, would my code attempt to spawn the same number of threads as the MaxDegreeOfParallelism value?

**EDIT 1**

If not, could I achieve something similar with the below code:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        public async Task sendRequest(string url)
        {
            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing " + url);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Response for " + url + " " + resp);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Response for " + url + " " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] urls = { "https://example1.com", "https://example2.com", "https://example3.com", "https://example4.com", "https://example5.com" };
            foreach (string url in urls)
            {
                Program program = new Program();
                //dont await the sendRequest() method so that you can go through whole loop
                Thread operation = new Thread(() => program.sendRequest(url));
                operation.Start();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want one task for each string in the array?

Comment: Side note: you are missing `using` on `response`, and the `HttpClient` should be stored in a static field

Comment: @Magnus Yes, and I want them spawned all "at once". From my research it seems that the ```Parallel.ForEachAsync``` implementation decides on its own how many threads to open in parallel. So, if I had an array of 100 URLs, 100 threads may not be necessarily spawned at once. Maybe less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MaxDegreeOfParallelism to the size of the array, does this also act as an implied minimum degree of parallelism?

No. There is no "minimum degree of parallelism", since the code should still run even on a single core CPU.

> would my code attempt to spawn the same number of threads as the MaxDegreeOfParallelism value?

No, it is allowed to use as many threads as `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` , but does not have to. Using more threads than logical CPU cores would be inefficient for compute bound workloads, so it will try to keep the number as threads as small as possible  while still using as much CPU as possible, but I'm not sure about the exact details. Unless you have some reason to do otherwise I would suggest just not setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and let the loop use its default behavior.

Note that the main benefit of parallel loops are when running compute bound code. Your example seem to be strictly IO bound, so will probably not gain much benefit over using something like this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(async url => {...}));
```

This will start all requests *sequentially*, let the requests run *concurrently*, and then process the result *sequentially* again.

Comment: What if I looped through the entire array and in each iteration, I open a new thread that calls the method to send the HTTP request. ```Thread operation = new Thread(() => request.Send(url));``` .I can choose not to await the method so that I go through the whole array. Would this be advisable under the condition that I am doing mostly IO bound tasks?

Comment: @TriedAtLeast No, the whole point of async/await is to *not* use a thread for each IO operation.

Comment: Just to be clear by what I meant I have added an edit to my question. Would the code in that edit still be ill-advised?

Comment: @TriedAtLeast In your updated example you start a bunch of threads, *but the threads do almost nothing*!, So you will have the overhead of starting a bunch of threads, but gain little from it. Again, the correct approach is most likely to use a single thread to start all asynch operations, and once all are started, wait for them all to complete. I would highly recommend reading [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)